# How to set/manipulate an unbound Option Group in MS Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access, radio-button

I made an Unbound **Option Group** in my Form that looks like this:

[image]

Its Option Values are **1 for Available, 2 for Reserved, 3 for Unavailable** and named as **check1, check2, check3** respectively. In my function below (User clicks the List/Table):

```
Private Sub listBooks_AfterUpdate()

    BookModule.setBookStatus status:=Me.listBooks.Column(6), check1:=Me.check1, check2:=Me.check2, check3:=Me.check3
    'Debug.Print Me.check1.Value
    
End Sub
```

where method `setBookStatus` is defined as:

```
Public Sub setBookStatus(status As Integer, check1 As CheckBox, check2 As CheckBox, check3 As CheckBox)
    
    If status = 1 Then
        check1.Value = True
        check2.Value = False
        check3.Value = False
    End If
    
    If status = 2 Then
        check1.Value = False
        check2.Value = True
        check3.Value = False
    End If
    
    If status = 3 Then
        check1.Value = False
        check2.Value = False
        check3.Value = True
    End If
    
End Sub
```

But upon running I am getting this error:

```
Run-Time error '2448':

You can't assign a value to this object.
```

If I execute this `?Me!MyCheckBox.Value` or `?Me!MyCheckBox` in my Immediate Window, I am getting this:

```
Compile error:

Variable not yet created in this context
```

Hope someone can help me with what I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option group is linked. You set and get it as a whole, and don't manipulate the individual checkboxes. They automatically get checked/unchecked

The sub could be as simple as:

```
Public Sub setBookStatus(status As Integer, optGroupFrame As OptionGroup)
   optGroupFrame = status
End Sub
```

Or, of course, omitted altogether since you don't need subs to replace single simple lines of code.

If you do want to manipulate individual checkboxes, well, don't use an option group.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I get Option Behavior.